# How to stop an Event to run again in simple JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

**My Code is below.**

Now what I want is that, the event execute only on first `mouseover` after that it should become disable, which means if user `mouseover` again it should do nothing:

> HTML is below !

```
<div id="welcomehomebtndiv">
    <button id="welcomehomebtnteacher" type="button">Teacher</button>
    <button id="welcomehomebtnstudent" type="button">Student</button>
    </div>
```

> actual function is this !

```
document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher").addEventListener("mouseover", removebtn);

    function removebtn() {
        var parent = document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher");
        var child = document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnstudent");
        parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is removing the button. Do you want to remove the button or just to remove the event listener?

Comment: yes. should remove the button on first event call.and then Event should not run again onMouseOver.

Comment: Then after you removed the button the event would not be fired anymore! I think the only thing you need to change is `var parent = document.getElementById("welcomehomebtndiv");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to add a flag and check if it's already raised or not:

```
var childRemoved = false;
document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher").addEventListener("mouseover", removebtn);

function removebtn() {
    if (!childRemoved) {
      var parent = document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher");
      var child = document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnstudent");
      parent.removeChild(child);
      childRemoved = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the event listerer just unbind the event;

```
function removebtn(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener('mouseover', removebtn);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Teacher** button will be disabled & will **NOT REMOVE THE BUTTON**.Hope this your criteria.If this is so you can use disabled=true;

```
document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher").addEventListener("mouseover", removebtn);
function removebtn() {
     document.getElementById("welcomehomebtnteacher").disabled =true;
 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9tub9th4/2/)